# UrlImageViewHelper resize image with ImageView size

Tags: java, android, resize, imageview, urlimageviewhelper

I'm using `UrlImageViewHelper`, I would like to use less memory. So I thought about resizing image downloaded and fit with imageView size (more or less small depending on screen). Is it possible?

Here is my code :

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(mImageReport, mCurrentReportString.getUrlImages());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use [ https://github.com/square/picasso ] to load and cache, resize Image from Image Url . 
Picasso.with(getActivity()) 
    .load(imageUrl) 
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) 
    .error(R.drawable.error) 
    .resize(screenWidth, imageHeight)
    .centerInside() 
    .into(imageView);